# hide / show  program window

Tags: windows, vb.net

I'm using `Visual Basic 2008`

for example i have running `notepad.exe`, can i hide notepad window, and then if i need it to show it again?

thanks.

Comment: This is way more difficult than you think. If you're a beginning programmer trying to learn VB.NET, then this is the last thing you need to be trying to do. It requires that you call functions from the Windows API, using P/Invoke to call unmanaged code from managed code. It's possible, but I don't necessarily recommend it. What problem are you trying to solve? Why does your application need to control other applications (like Notepad)? Programs should run independently of other programs. If you need to edit text, use the `TextBox` control in the toolbox; it's almost identical to Notepad anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Call [`Process.GetProcessesByName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) passing `"notepad"`.
- Then read [`MainWindowHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx) from the returned process.
- P/Invoke [`ShowWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passing `SW_HIDE` or `SW_SHOW` to hide/show the window.

The [P/Invoke signature](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow) is:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
```

The [`ShowWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) topic lists the numeric values for the `SW_*` flags.

---

Thanks to @Alex K for suggesting as a comment the use of [`ShowWindowAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than `ShowWindow()`.

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function ShowWindowAsync(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
```

From the documentation:

> This function posts a show-window
>   event to the message queue of the
>   given window. An application can use
>   this function to avoid becoming
>   nonresponsive while waiting for a
>   nonresponsive application to finish
>   processing a show-window event.

Comment: Better to use `ShowWindowAsync` as its geared towards windows owned by a diff thread and wont block if the targets hung/non responsive. (identical prototype)

Comment: thanks, to get it to work i changed nCmdShow type to integer, it works good, but.. it hides window, but then i can't show it, SW_SHOW value is 5 and i have tried ShowWindowAsync(hwnd, 5) and nothing happen... what is wrong?

Comment: @John: You pass 0 (`SW_HIDE`) the first time to hide the window, and 5 (`SW_SHOW`) the second time to show the window? What part doesn't work? You don't see the window on the screen?